# After Effects - create a square mask and have an image slide through it

Tags: adobe-after-effects

I have a rectangular image, let's pretend it's a wide picture of New York city's skyline.

I want to create a rectangle in the center of my canvas. Then I want to horizontally slide the picture of New York through the rectangle, so only part of it is showing at a time.

How can I do this?

**What I've tried:**

1. Right click the image layer, then "Mask" > "New Mask". Resize the mask square to be the size I want. *Problem:* When I translate the image horizontally, the mask moves with it.
2. If I create a mask as a seperate layer, it doesn't hide the image.

Comment: I'm confused you already said how. Create a square mask.. have your image slide through it. What part are you actually stuck on?

Comment: If I create a mask as part of the image layer - then when I translate the image layer, the mask moves with it.

If I create a mask as a seperate layer, it doesn't hide the image

Comment: you want to *pan*?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a better fit on http://video.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you just need to select your Tracking

[image: Toggle Modes]

Then choose Alpha Matte Tracking on the Layer *below* the Mask

[image: Alpha Matte]